# How can I iterate over nested json dicts?

Tags: python, json

I've been trying to figure out how I can iterate over a json like object, so I could get a user id by its name.

**json**

```
{
    "ApiSearchResult": [
        {
            "totalNumberResults": 55,
            "type": "User",
            "searchResults": [
                {
                    "firstName": "shashank",
                    "name": "0o_shashank._o0",
                    "uid": 81097836
                },
                {
                    "firstName": "Shahnawaz",
                    "name": "0shahnawaz.0",
                    "uid": 83697589
                },
                {
                    "firstName": "Ashu",
                    "name": "ashu.-3",
                    "uid": 83646061
                },
                {
                    "bgImage": "photoalbum_491396460_user82597906-1-jpeg.jpg",
                    "firstName": "Garfield",
                    "name": "beast.boy",
                    "uid": 82597906
                },
                {
                    "firstName": "Bharath",
                    "name": "bharath_mohan69",
                    "uid": 80197615
                },
                {
                    "bgImage": "photoalbum_481041410_user79819261-1-jpg.jpg",
                    "firstName": "Wille-ICE",
                    "name": "blowhole",
                    "uid": 79819261
                }
           ]
       }
    ]
 }
```

***Python***

```
def getidbyname(name):
    event = response['ApiSearchResult'][0]['searchResults'][0]
    for key, value in event.iteritems():
        if value == name: continue
        elif key == "uid":
            return value
```

But, this won't work, I've never really worked with this many nested elements.

Comment: Are you using nested dictionaries? There are libraries for dealing with JSONs in python. https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def getidbyname(name): 
    for i in data['ApiSearchResult'][0]['searchResults']:
        if i['name'] == name:
            return i['uid']
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but I added the [0] at the end because I thought `searchResults` had a list. But that didn't do what I needed, but this works.

Answer (score 2):

This might work if your response is already a python dictionary:

```
def getidbyname(name):
    for event in data["ApiSearchResult"][0]["searchResults"]:
        if event["name"] == name:
            return event["uid"]
```

If your input is a text value, you need to use `json.loads(response)` to get a python dictionary out of it.